# rotating an element based on how many yes radioboxes are clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to rotate a needle on a "speedometer" by looking for each click of a "yes" on a survey, and for each click I would like to rotate the needle by a couple of degrees, but i don't exaclty know how to get that effects. 
This is what I got:

```
jQuery('input[value="Yes"]').on('click', function (){


        jQuery('#progress').animate( marginBottom: +=4 }, 
        {
            step: function(now,fx) {
                jQuery(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
                };  


        });
```

css:

```
#progress{
top: 78px;
left: 34px;
height: 0px;
width: 130px;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid #232323;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
```

}

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pTkkS/2/

Comment: can you provide a test page on jsfiddle.net and paste the link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTkkS/6/)*

```
$('input[value=Yes]').on('change', function() {
    $('#progress').animate(
        {
            marginBottom: '+=4'
        },{
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css({transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'});
        }
    });
});
```